# Where does the Static members reside in memory,is it permanent generation?

Tags: java, memory-management, static, static-members, permanent-generation

Static members where does they reside.
i need an detail explanation of static ,local and instance members memory allocation(variables,methods).
Memory management(Is it permanent generation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static members : permanent generation(heap)

local variable : stack memory which is not heap.
refer here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html

Comment: This is not true for newest Java versions unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Java version you are using:

1. Pre Java8: statics (just like other "permanent" things) were stored in a `PermGen`. It's simply part of the memory model like young gen and old gen.
2. Java8: here PermGen got removed! For a number of reasons, for instance it was hard to tune it. Of course all the data didn't just got abandoned, since we still need it. It was just moved to `Metaspace`, which resides inside native memory (so outside Java heap).